I'm currently reading a romanized, english map of China from 1912. I'd like to modernize the locations. How should I go about it?
I'm reading a map from 1916 that has outdated romanization and location names. While I am easily finding the bigger towns, cities, and districts I struggle when it comes to the more minor towns. I'm struggling a little to compare the romanization to modern romanization as well. While it'd be fine to simply use the towns on the old map, I would at least like to update the romanization which is what I'd need help in. How would I figure out the differences between romanizations, and how - if possible - would I find the modern towns on a modern map?
As reference, this is the map from 1916:
https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:1916_maps_of_China#/media/File:A_map_of_China_prepared_for_the_China_Inland_Mission_-_btv1b530644162.jpg

I think the romanization used in that map is Chinese postal romanization. I can't find a comprehensive table listing all places.
If I want to be accurate just for a few places, I would open a modern map and put it side by side for comparison. Minor towns can be roughly located based on the surrounding major cities. You can also use the reference [a] on wiki to check.
If I want to save some time to update many places, I'll actually ask ChatGPT first, like
Can you show me the modern Chinese name and its pinyin for the following in Chinese postal romanization?

Paotingfu
Chenchowfu
Ninghaihsien

Here's the answer. It looks good.
Paotingfu - 保定府

Modern Name and Pinyin: 保定 (Bǎodìng)

Chenchowfu - 陳州府

Modern Name and Pinyin: 淮阳 (Huáiyáng) (Note: Today, this area is part of Henan province and has evolved administratively.)

Ninghaihsien - 寧海縣

Modern Name and Pinyin: 宁海 (Nínghǎi)


After searching around for a bit, I actually did find a table of all the names using an atlas that this map seems to be based on. They have latitude and longitude associated, and while it's slightly off I can calculate the small difference to discover the correct location. Further, I found a book for sale on Postal Rominization by the Chinese Republic at the time that would be useful if I'm willing to pay over 100 dollars. I find it unfortunate there's so few resources in English regarding this specific subject.
